# Positioning and editing the newly created row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm making a table.

I've made my rows editable with: `ng-click="todo.editing = !todo.editing"`

index.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in todos>
    <td>
        <div ng-hide="todo.editing">{{ todo.id }} </div>
        <div ng-show="todo.editing"><input type="id" ng-model="todo.id" /></div>
    </td>
    <td>                
       <div ng-hide="todo.editing">{{ todo.text }}</div>
       <div ng-show="todo.editing"><input type="text" ng-model="todo.text" /></div>
   </td>
</tr>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm ng-scope" ng-click="todo.editing = !todo.editing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
```

I've made a button to add new rows to the table:

index.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block " ng-click="addRow($storage.todos)">New record</button>
```

script.js

```
$scope.addRow = function (arr) {
    console.log(arr);
    arr.push({'id':$scope.id, 'text': $scope.text});
};
```

Now I want to expand my addRow() function so I can add a new row and at the same time position myself at that  row, and also put me in edit mode.

The problem with position is that I am using pagination. Let's say I am at page one in pagination and the newly row comes at page four. I want to automatically get there.

Can somebody give me a hint? Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is your text field?

Comment: To put the new row in editable mode, `arr.push({ id: $scope.id, text: $scope.text, editing: true })` ?

Comment: You will need to store a reference to the row you are editing somewhere. After that you need to create some type of "Edit Mode." You could do this by wrapping the guts of your ng-repeat in an ng-if. If the current ID is the ID that is being edited show a form with input fields instead of plain text.

Comment: I add the missing code messerbill, Komo I used your proposal, it works and it solves the auto edit mode. Toni W I will see what I can do I'll come with response. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `editing` property value `true` during pushing.

Like this

```
arr.push({'id':$scope.id, 'text': $scope.text,editing:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0t1trq6m/

`addRow()` method now looks like:

```
$scope.addRow = function () {
 console.log("test");
 var e = new Entry();
 e.id = $scope.todos.length;
 e.text = $scope.content;
 $scope.todos.push(e);
}
```